# How to change text color in contact form7?

Tags: css, contact-form-7

i need to change text color in contact form7.
that code is below.

```
--------------  
<label> Your name
[text* your-name class:accent class:form-fluid ] </label>

<label> Your email
[email* your-email class:form-fluid] </label>

<label> Subject
[text* your-subject class:form-fluid] </label>

<label> Your message (optional)
[textarea your-message] </label>


[submit "Submit"]
--------------------------
```

in this code i want to change color of the text like your name , your message to white color
now that text color is black
how can i fix it usuing css??
i am beginner. plz help me

http://blackparrot.life

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of name, your message and titles:

```
.wpcf7-form label {color: #fff !important;}
.wpcf7-submit {color: #000 !important;}
```

Color. It is white. To change it you need to change #fff.

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I87N1.png